# Django custom UsernameField form validation not working

Tags: django, validation, mongoengine

So I created a custom form field to validate for duplicate usernames. I'm using Django + Mongoengine as my database. I have that plugged and working with the django authentication system so I'm assuming it can be accessed from forms.py? Maybe that assumption is incorrect. So I have the field

```
class UsernameField(CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            return ""
        return value

    def validate(self, value):
        super(CharField, self).validate(value)

        try:
            # If the user object exists it won't throw an Error/Exception
            user=User.objects.get(username=value) 
            raise ValidationError("Username already exists")
        except:
            pass
```

But when I actually use it in my form, it always seems to validate correctly even though I've called checked if form.is_valid() is True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, it was a dumb mistake on my part. For some reason I forgot that the Error I was trying to raise would be caught by the try and I would get sent to the except route. Changing it to this works

```
class UsernameField(CharField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            return ""
        return value

    def validate(self, value):
        super(CharField, self).validate(value)
        usernameDuplicate = False

        try:
            # If the user object exists it won't throw an Error/Exception
            user=User.objects.get(username=value) 
            usernameDuplicate = True
        except:
            pass

        if usernameDuplicate==True:
            raise ValidationError("Username already exists")
```

Comment: The lesson you should have learned is never ever to use blank excepts. Always catch exactly the exceptions you think might happen - in this case, User.DoesNotExist and User.MultipleObjectsReturned.

Answer (score 1):

You're raising exceptions in the try block but then snuffing them out in the except block with pass. Try this, it will check for the existing user and only fails if it exists.

```
    try:
        # If the user object doesn't exist, it validates
        user=User.objects.get(username=value) 
    except django.core.exceptions.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
         #user does exist, barf.
        raise ValidationError("Username already exists")
```